# ASP.NET, MVC and Dynamic Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dynamic-data

Will ASP.NET MVC ever support Dynamic Data or some other means of scaffolding? I know MVC web apps support scaffolding CRUD pages from linq contexts (and entities too I think).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic Data has since been absorbed into ASP.Net MVC as Html.DisplayFor, [Html.EditorFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorfor%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), and [MVC EditorTemplates](http://coding-in.net/asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-use-editortemplates/).

Answer (score 2):

Scott Hanselman has a page about getting these technologies running side-by side.

Check out: [ASP.NET WebForms and ASP.MVC and ASP.NET Dynamic Data Side By Side](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

MVC support is a [part of the Dynamic Data Futures](http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=15459) project. This was released initially in July 2008. It's a bit buggy, since it was an early release intended to generate feedback, but the bottom line is that they are working on it.